# how replace url with url using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code...and as you can see there is a below url in the code,

http://i1263.photobucket.com/albums/ii624/davgrig04/suitmeasurementchart.jpg

I want to replace this url with another url when the page loads using jquery or java...how should i do that? ...Please explain in easy words...as i have 0 knowledge about java...

```html
<td width="664" valign="top" style="padding: 0in 5.4pt; border: 1pt solid #78c0d4;">
<p style="text-align: left;"><span color="#006988" face="Courier" style="color: #006988; font-family: Courier;"><a href="http://i1263.photobucket.com/albums/ii624/davgrig04/suitmeasurementchart.jpg"><b>Measurement Chart</b></a></span></p>
</td>
```

Comment: are you using some `JS` library like `jQuery`?

Answer (score 2):

Add `id` to `<a>` tag.

```
<a id="myChart" href="http://i1263.photobucket.com/albums/ii624/davgrig04/suitmeasurementchart.jpg">
```

Add `JavaScript`

```
document.getElementById("#myChart").href = "new_chart_file.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the  tag as @Hamza Rashid said.

To make sure the url is changed when the window loads, add this function:

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("#myChart").href = "new_chart_file.jpg";
};
```